# Passing Event Handler From Grandparent to GrandChild Component in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I understand how to pass a click event from a parent component to a child component in React, but don't understand how I can pass it from a grandparent to a grandchild without making the parent clickable.

In the following example, I'd like for the parent div to close upon clicking the grandchild div.

Here is my code, which does not work. Thx!

```
var Grandparent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
    return {open: true};
  },
  close: function() {
    this.setState({open: false});
  },
    render() {
    var grandparentBox={backgroundColor: 'yellow', height: 400, width: 400};
        return <div style = {grandparentBox}><Parent open={this.state.open} close = {this.close}/></div>;
  }
});

var Parent = React.createClass({
    render() {
    var parentBox={backgroundColor: 'red', height: 100, width: 100};
        if (this.props.open == true) {
            return <div close={this.props.close} style = {parentBox}><Grandchild/></div>
      }
      else {
        return null;
      }
  }
});

var Grandchild = React.createClass({
    render() {
    var grandchildBox={backgroundColor: 'black', height: 20, width: 20, top: 0};
        return <div onClick={this.props.close} style = {grandchildBox}></div>

  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Grandparent/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to pass the close method as a prop to the Grandchild component (instead of the div that's wrapping it). As it is, Grandchild doesn't have a method this.props.close...

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
    render() {
        var parentBoxStyle = {backgroundColor: 'red', height: 100, width: 100};
        if (this.props.open == true) {
            return <div style={parentBoxStyle}>
                <Grandchild close={this.props.close} />
            </div>
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But if I pass Grandchild the close method, it's not doing anything with onClick.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but clicking the grandchild closes both the grandchild and the parent in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chadlieberman/55htLpgL/).

Comment: Thank you Chad, the problem is that I want ONLY the grandchild to be able to handle clicks. When you click on the parent, it shouldn't close, but when you click on the Grandchild, both should close.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought you wanted. Have you tried it in the fiddle I linked above? I am clicking the red and yellow areas and nothing happens. Then I click the black box and both black and red close. Are you looking for something else?

Comment: Oh I didn't see that- THANK YOU Chad! Works!:)

Comment: Great! Also, see spro's edits above for some better style ;P