# Child component notify Grandparent - react functional

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-typescript

I have a issue to send information to grandparent component. So this is the tree of components

tableComponent -> modalComponent -> formComponent

If user click on formComponent modal will close and need to send information to tableComponent to refresh state in useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
    getApi()
      .then((getData) => {
        showTable(getData)

      })
      .catch((error) => {})
  }, [])
```

Here is data that need again to fetch information if submit on form.
how I can solve the issue?

Thanks!!!

Comment: This is one of the tricky parts of React. You can look in-to the context API or a library like Redux (easy-peasy.) It's kind of hard to help you with the code you have provided. The usual flow would be to add the function to the grandparent component and then pass it down via modalComponent and to formCompoment  and then have it be called in formComponent. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39255641/passing-event-handler-from-grandparent-to-grandchild-component-in-reactjs

Comment: put the update form input state in the useEffect dependency array